# How can I extract subscription priority from ReportServerXML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xquery, reportserver

I'm working in SQL Server 2014 and with Microsofts out of the box ReportServer database. I've been tasks with creating a script that will pull the subscription priority because of this [bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2731402).

I've written the following query using: SQL, XQuery, and XPath.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition','http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd )
,s
as (SELECT  
      s.Report_OID
     ,s.SubscriptionID
     ,s.OwnerID
     ,s.Description 
     ,s.LastStatus
     ,s.EventType
     ,CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),s.ExtensionSettings)) AS reportXML
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions as s
    WHERE s.ExtensionSettings is not null
   )
--SELECT s.reportxml.value('/ParameterValues[1]','varchar(150)') FROM s

SELECT 
 con.Report_OID
,con.test
FROM (SELECT 
       s.Report_OID
      ,dsn.value('Name[1]','varchar(150)') as test
      FROM s
      cross apply reportxml.nodes('/ParameterValues/ParameterValue')  as r(dsn)
     ) con
```

I also have 2 example xml documents that are pasted below.

```
   <ParameterValues>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Name>FILENAME</Name>
        <Field>subscriber_domestic_id</Field>
      </ParameterValue>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Name>PATH</Name>
        <Field>folder</Field>
      </ParameterValue>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Name>RENDER_FORMAT</Name>
        <Value>PDF</Value>
      </ParameterValue>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Name>WRITEMODE</Name>
        <Value>OverWrite</Value>
      </ParameterValue>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Name>FILEEXTN</Name>
        <Value>True</Value>
      </ParameterValue>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Name>USERNAME</Name>
        <Field>login</Field>
      </ParameterValue>
      <ParameterValue>
        <Name>PASSWORD</Name>
        <Field>mypasswordstackOF</Field>
      </ParameterValue>
    </ParameterValues>

The second document here.

<ParameterValues>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>TO</Name>
    <Value>jonjones@email.com;billiejean@email.com;prettyfloyd@email.com</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>CC</Name>
    <Value>a@email.com;g@email.com.com;</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>IncludeReport</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>RenderFormat</Name>
    <Value>PDF</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>Subject</Name>
    <Value>@ReportName was executed at @ExecutionTime</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>IncludeLink</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
  <ParameterValue>
    <Name>Priority</Name>
    <Value>NORMAL</Value>
  </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

From this you can see that not all documents have a priority. My current query doesn't error out but it does not return anything. I believe i'm using the nodes() function correctly. Any ideas on how to correctly approach this?

Comment: Tried OUTER APPLY?

Comment: Yes it returns Report_OID no problem but is null for test column.

Comment: Do you need this namespaces? Your XML have no namespaces specified. Try with `WITH s as (SELECT  ...` only.

Comment: I am getting results now. Thank you! I'll have to fix xml query now.

Comment: @PawełDyl Do you mind providing me with resources where I can learn more about xpath and xquery? I've already came across msdn, w3 schools, and ect. Perhaps you know of some gems.

Comment: 1. Read, 2. Practice, 3. Go to 1 :) No gems, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future purposes and if someone is looking to accomplish the same type of extraction, I'm pasting my code below:

```
;WITH
s
as (SELECT  
      s.Report_OID
     ,s.SubscriptionID
     ,s.OwnerID
     ,s.Description 
     ,s.LastStatus
     ,s.EventType
     ,CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),s.ExtensionSettings)) AS reportXML
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions as s (NOLOCK)
    WHERE s.ExtensionSettings is not null
   )

SELECT 
 con.Report_OID
,con.Node
,con.PriorityLevel
INTO #Temp
FROM (SELECT 
       s.Report_OID
      ,dsn.value('Name[1]','varchar(150)') as Node
      ,dsn.value('Value[1]','varchar(150)') as PriorityLevel
      FROM s
      cross apply reportxml.nodes('/ParameterValues/ParameterValue')  as r(dsn)
     ) con

SELECT 
 t.Report_OID
,c.Name as 'ReportName'
,t.Node
,t.PriorityLevel
,c.Path
FROM #Temp t
    join ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c (NOLOCK)
        on t.Report_OID = c.ItemID 
WHERE 1=1 
and Node = 'Priority'
```

Enjoy!